# Twitter hashtag

Tags: twitter, social-networking

I want to add twitter hastag widget to my application how do I do it. the feature should ask the user to add teh hash tag of the particular thing and add it to his profile page, how do I do that.

Please suggest me the logic and implementation

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the solution for this problem i was able to retrieve feeds from the twitter and post it on my web app, I search for particular hash tag and the feeds of that particular hash tag will be displayed

here is the code,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">    
   $(document).ready(function() // don't do anything until the document is loaded.
   {    
   $("#submit").click(function(event){ // wire up this as an onclick event to the submit button.
var searchTerm = $("#search").val()  ; // get the user-entered search term
var baseUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23"; 
$.getJSON(baseUrl + searchTerm + "&rpp=1500&callback=?", function(data) // call getJSON providing the complete url with search term and a JSONP callback
{
$("#tweets").empty(); // clear out any previous results.
if(data.results.length < 1) // friendly "no results"
  $('#tweets').html("No results JOINEVENTUS"); 
$.each(data.results, function() // iterate over the results;
{
$('<div align="justify"></div>')
.hide()
.append('<img src="' + this.profile_image_url + '" width="80px" /> ')
.append('<span><a href="http://www.twitter.com/'
+ this.from_user + '">' + this.from_user 
+ '</a> ' + makeLink(this.text) + '</span>')
.appendTo('#tweets') // append the constructed results HTML to the tweets div
.fadeIn(2000); // fade in the results over 2 seconds.
});
});
});
});

function makeLink(text) // this REGEX converts http(s) links that are embedded in the tweet text into real hyperlinks.
{   
var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;   
return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 
} 
</script> 
</HEAD>
<BODY style="margin-left:20%;margin-right:20%"> 
<div align="center">
<h2>Twitter tag search</h2>
<div>Enter Search Term</div>
<input type="text" id=search />
<input type="button" id=submit value="Search" /> 
<DIV id="tweets" />  
</div>

</BODY>
```